# On Android, how to launch app "com.android.launcher" or "com.android.systemui"

Tags: android

I tried `Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkg);`, but it returned `null`.

Should I use `context.startActivity(intent);` ? If so, how to get the `intent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those are apps that are designed to be launched, AFAIK. If you want to bring up the user's chosen home screen, create an `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME` `Intent` and call `startActivity()` on it:

```
Intent home = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
home.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(home);
```

Comment: Thanks! action_main or action_home? How to get to the launcher GUI?

Comment: @JackWM: "action_main or action_home?" -- sorry, it was `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_HOME` (see updated answer). "How to get to the launcher GUI?" -- if by "launcher GUI" you mean "show the list of available activities to launch", the user has to do that. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of home screen implementations, all of which do that however they want. There's no programmatic way to cause it to happen across the board.

Comment: Good updating! But I mean the "launcher GUI" is the GUI when user tab "Home" button" and then the button with two lines of "..." and a circle.

Comment: @JackWM: Again, the user has to do that -- you have no way of programmatically having the home screen do that for you.

Comment: All right. Got you! Thanks a lot!